# Line counting and abberant results

Tags: c, linux, line-count

I'm writing a utility to count the lines in a given file via the Unix command line.  Normally this would be dead simple for me, but apparently I'm having a major off night.  The goal of this program is to take in an unknown number of files from the command line, read them into a buffer and check for the newline character.  Sounds simple?

```
int size= 4096;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int fd, i, j, c, fileLines, totalLines;
  char *buf= (char *)malloc(size); //read buffer

  for (i=2; i<argc; i++){ //get first file

    fileLines=1;    

    if ((fd=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY))!= -1){ //open, read, print file count, close
        while ((c= read(fd, buf, size))!= 0){

            for (j=0; j<size; j++){
                if (buf[j] == '\n')
                    fileLines++;
            }
        }

    }
    printf("%s had %d lines of text\n", argv[i], fileLines);
    totalLines+= fileLines;
    close(fd);

  }

  printf("%d lines were counted overall\n", totalLines);    
  return 0;
}
```

I have two problems.  The first is that the first printf statement is never executed outside of the debugger.  The second thing is the totalLines printout should be roughly 175K lines, but the printed value is about 767 times larger.

I'm having trouble understanding this, because all the relevant variables have been declared out of scope from their modification, but that still doesn't explain why the first print statemeent and line counter update is ignored outside of the debugger along with the abberant totalLines result

Any help is appreciated.

**ANSWER**

Two changes were suggested.
The first was to change `j<size` to `j<c`.  While this was not the solution required, it follows good coding convention

The second was to change `i=2` to `i=1`.  The reason I had the original start variable was the way I started the debugger executable.  In the gdb command line, I entered in `run lc1 f1.txt` to start the debugger.  This resulted in the arglist having three variables, and I didn't know that `run f1.txt` was perfectly suitable, since my professor introduced us to gdb by using the first example.

Comment: Only one file is open at a time, due to the for loop iterating sequentially through the arg list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider: `./program file.txt`

```
argv[0] is "program"
argv[1] is "file.txt"
```

which means your `for` loop starts from the wrong index, and if you are passing only 1 file through the cmd line your code will never enter in that loop! It should start at index 1:

```
for (i=1; i<argc; i++){
```

Do yourself a favor and initialize all variables when you declare them. Is the only way to ensure that there will be no garbage on those memory locations.

Comment: I just asked a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891964/command-line-argument-list-discrepancy-between-debugger-and-executable about this topic and would like your thoughts on it.

Comment: It was this adjustment that did the trick.  It turned out I was entering in `run program file.txt1` in the gdb prompt, which threw off my arglist counter by 1.

Answer (score 3):

You're not initializing `totalLines`.  You increment it inside of your loop, but you don't set it to 0 when you first declare it.

Also, why do you start from `i=2`?  This is the third command-line argument, and the second parameter to your program.  Is this what you intended, or did you want to start from the first parameter to your program?

And as others have pointed out, you should have `j < c` instead of `j < size`.

Comment: You were right about that, and the program performs as expected stepping through the debugger.  However, the command line output shows only the second printf with a totalLines value of 0.  Also, I looked through the command line arguments.  arg[0] was the file path to the executable, arg[1] was the executable name, and arg[2] was the first input file to be processed

Comment: @Jason - Yes, that was not the only issue.  As others have noted, try using `i = 1` and `j < c` in your loops.

Comment: @Jason - And that's really bizarre about the arguments.  Every resource I can find says that `argv[0]` should be the program name, and `argv[1]` should be the first parameter to the program.

Comment: @Jason: You need to look again. argv[1] cannot possibly be the executable name, unless you're calling your application with `myapp myapp somefile someotherfile`.

Comment: Ken White, check my question for the solution to my problem.  The confusion was a result of my professor's method of starting the executable in the gdb command line

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is wrong. It should be `j=0; j<c; j++`. That's probably not directly responsible for the errors you're seeing but will definitely cause problems.

Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: You and tmg were right about the bug, but it didn't change the results.

Comment: the first printout shows up in the debugger, but not int the command line

Answer (score 1):

First, excellent question. :) All the necessary code, well stated, and it's obvious you've done your work. :)

How are you *starting* your program when in the debugger? I think the `argv[2]` starting point might be related to not reaching the `printf()`, but it would depend upon how you're starting. More details below.

A few comments:

> ```
> int size= 4096;
> ```

Typically, C preprocessor macros are used for this kind of magic number. I know your teachers probably said to never use the preprocessor, but idiomatic C would read:

```
#define SIZE 4096
```

> ```
> for (i=2; i<argc; i++){ //get first file
> ```

Try `i=1` -- `argv[0]` is the name of the program, `argv[1]` is going to be the first command line argument -- presumably if someone calls it via `./wc foo` you want to count the number of lines in the file `foo`. :) (Also, you want the loop to terminate. :) Of course, if you're trying to write a replacement for `wc -l`, then your loop is alright, but not very helpful if someone screws up the arguments. That can safely be kept as a project for later. (If you're curious now, read the `getopt(3)` manpage. :)

```
    if ((fd=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY))!= -1){
        while ((c= read(fd, buf, size))!= 0){

            for (j=0; j<size; j++){
```

You are ending the loop at `j<size` -- but you only read in `c` characters in the last block. You're reading left-over garbage on the last block. (I wouldn't be surprised if there are generated files in `/proc/` that might return short reads out of convenience for kernel programmers.)

```
                if (buf[j] == '\n')
                    fileLines++;
            }
        }

    }
    printf("%s had %d lines of text\n", argv[i], fileLines);
    totalLines+= fileLines;
```

This is the first time you've assigned to `totalLines`. :) It is liable to have garbage initial value.

```
    close(fd);
```

You should probably move the `close(fd);` call into the `if((fd=open()))` block; if the open failed, this will call `close(-1);`. Not a big deal, but if you were checking the `close(2)` error return (always good practice), it'd return a needless error.

```
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Changing i to 1 did the trick.  The thing that threw me off is I had the debugger display the arglis variables. arg[0] was the file path to the executable, arg[1] was the executable itself, and arg[2] was the text file to be processed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably aware of [wc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29), but I'll mention it just in case.

I know it doesn't directly help you debug your specific problem, but maybe you could glance at the source code and/or use it to verify that your program is working.

Answer (score 0):

You have logical error in for() loop. You should use "bytes read" instead "read up to", what I mean in your code use "c" instead "size" in for()