# Command line argument list discrepancy between debugger and executable

Tags: linux, gdb, command-line-arguments

I had this bite me in a certain sensitive spot this evening, and would like some clarification.  As karlphillip said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891838/line-counting-and-abberant-results/5891916#5891916), the executable sees the argument list as

```
Consider: ./program file.txt

argv[0] is "program"
argv[1] is "file.txt"
```

However, in the gdb debugger, for the program `./lc1 f1.txt`, the arglist shows as

```
arg[0] is "/home/jason/Project 6/lc1"
arg[1] is "lc1"
arg[2] is "f1.txt"
```

Why the discrepancy between the two arglists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce that error. How are you running it on the gdb prompt?

I'm guessing you have

```
(gdb) run lc1 f1.txt
```

which is wrong. In the gdb prompt, it's supposed to be

```
(gdb) run f1.txt
```

That will reconcile with your normal execution.

Comment: That was it.  I was entering the first option in the gdb command line.  Funny thing, it was my prof that showed us that way of starting an executable in the debugger.